# Bind right/left arrow keys to <mat-tab-group> panels, to implement Carousel

Tags: angular, carousel, angular-material2

I am trying to figure out how I can cycle between tabs in a `<mat-tab-group>`.

I have this HTML:

```html
<div>
  <mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab id="mat-tab-0" class="suman-mat-tab" label="Controls">
      <app-outer-control-panel></app-outer-control-panel>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab id="mat-tab-1"  class="suman-mat-tab" label="Events List">
      <app-events-list></app-events-list>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab id="mat-tab-2"  class="suman-mat-tab" label="Generated Code">
      <app-generated-code></app-generated-code>
    </mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>
</div>
```

and here's my component:

```ts
import {Component, OnInit, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {ChromeDataService} from '../../shared/services/chrome-data-service';
import {Subscription, Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './current-run.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./current-run.component.scss']
})

@Inject(ChromeDataService)
export class CurrentRunComponent implements OnInit {

  keydownSub: Subscription;
  state = 0;
  total = 0;

  constructor(private data: ChromeDataService) {

  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.keydownSub && this.keydownSub.unsubscribe();
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.keydownSub = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'keyup').subscribe((v: KeyboardEvent) => {

      if (v && v.keyCode === 37) {
        this.goLeft();
      }
      if (v && v.keyCode === 39) {
        this.goRight();
      }

    });

  }

  goLeft() {
    this.total = this.total + 2;  // note that 2 = 3-1
    this.state = this.total % 3;
    // how to set focused mat-tab here ??
  }

  goRight() {
    this.total++;
    this.state = this.total % 3;
    // how to set focused mat-tab here ??
  }

}
```

I just need to know, how can I tell Material which tab is in focus?

To make it dynamic, instead of hardc oding to 3, I could probably count the number of elements with the class  `class="suman-mat-tab"`.

Comment: By the way, you also need to implement `OnDestroy`.

Comment: I have implemented `ngOnDestroy()`...do I need to implement `OnDestroy()`?

Comment: `OnDestroy` is an interface and should be imported from `@angular/core`. Something like `export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `selectedIndex` input (with one-way binding) on `MatTabGroup`:

```html
<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="state">
  <!-- ... -->
</mat-tab-group>
```

As a side note, you also have to implement the `OnDestroy` interface in order for your `ngOnDestroy` lifecycle hook to work:

```ts
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {
  ngOnDestroy() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/tabs-index-so)

Comment: I wonder why we have to implement that interface for it to work? Why wouldn't it just check at runtime if ngOnDestroy() exists as a method?

Comment: also how did you get the JS syntax highlighting in the OP? thx

Comment: @Olegzandr Okay... actually you don't have to implement it... https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5814

Comment: Yeah I am not surprised that you don't have to implement it - most of that type information is just erased (type erasure) obviously - the runtime code and the typing should be completely separate tmk

Comment: Yes I just updated my codebase, I think it's good to use the interfaces, they will become useful. If you like the question, please take a moment to upvote thx